# Python get messages received on Gmail at time

Tags: python, websocket, gmail-api

I'm trying to create a simple bot that whenever I get a message on Gmail, it write the content on a file, for now I only have a cron scheduler that get the messages within a interval of 2 minutes, but the best choice would be to get the message as I said, when I receive them in real time.

I didn't find much on the googleapis for gmail tho. For what I know I should create a websocket and then after that, how could I have the messages I just received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Push Notification using the [Cloud Pub/Sub API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/overview) in order to create a webhook for your notifications.

You can follow this [guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) to do a proper set up.